# Creating a simple escrow contract but currentState is not updated?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Escrow {
    
    enum State {AWAITING_PAYMENT, AWAITING_DELIVERY, COMPLETE}
    
    State public currentState;
    
    address public buyer;
    address public seller;
    
    modifier buyerOnly() { require(msg.sender == buyer); _; } 
    modifier inState(State expectedState) { require(currentState == expectedState); _; }
    
    constructor(address _buyer, address _seller) {
        buyer = _buyer;
        seller = _seller;
    }
    
    function confirmPayment() buyerOnly inState(State.AWAITING_PAYMENT) payable {
        currentState == State.AWAITING_DELIVERY;
    }
    
    function confirmDelivery() buyerOnly inState(State.AWAITING_DELIVERY) {
        seller.send(this.balance);
        currentState == State.COMPLETE;
        
    }
}
```

I sent 2 ether to the escrow contract and the state should change to `1`, which is `AWAITING_DELIVERY`, however state remains `0` and I am unable to `confirmDelivery`.

> **[vm] from:** 0xAb8...35cb2 **to:** Escrow.confirmDelivery() 0xa13...eAD95 **value:** 0 wei **data:** 0x5e1...0177b **logs:** 0 **hash:** 0xff9...e1277
>
> transact to Escrow.confirmDelivery errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

[currentState: 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU2Zl.png)

Comment: Which version of Solidity are you using? The first line suggests `0.4.21` but  the `constructor` keyword was introduced in `0.5`, so this code that you provided won't compile.

Comment: hmm.. the code compiled with 0.4.21 though.

Comment: It seems that you in fact compiled it with a different version, but you're just not aware of it. The [breaking changes list](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#syntax) between `0.4` and `0.5` states: "New keywords: calldata and constructor." which means that the `constructor` keyword didn't exist in `0.4` ... But it's ok, it's just going to be a little harder to find the solution.

Comment: So even though the documentation states, that the `constructor` keyword was added in version `0.5`, it is in fact available from version `0.4.22` (which is compatible with the `^0.4.21` value).

Answer (score 0):

The error was not related to the Solidity version. It was caused by using an incorrect expression for validating (`==`) instead of assigning (`=`).

Solution:

```
function confirmPayment() buyerOnly inState(State.AWAITING_PAYMENT) payable {
    currentState = State.AWAITING_DELIVERY;  // `=` instead of `==`
}
    
function confirmDelivery() buyerOnly inState(State.AWAITING_DELIVERY) {
    seller.send(this.balance);
    currentState = State.COMPLETE;  // `=` instead of `==`
}
```